# ASPX page HTML 5 or not

Tags: html

I want to make sure my page is HTML 5 standard or not.

The aspx page header part below. Is this page HTML5? I am very new to HTML. This is for the kind confirmation.

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Map.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">  
<title>Basemap Gallery - Bing Maps</title>  
...
</head>   
<body class="claro" style="background-image: url('Images/menubackground.png');" dir="<%=Direction()%>" >
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      ...
```

Comment: It’s very hard to figure out what you’re trying to ask here. For example, what do you mean by “slandered”? Is that a typo? And where did you get that HTML source from and what do you want to do with it? Do to perplexing bits like that, I think your question is at risk of getting downvoted and flagged and deleted. Whatever you could do to be more specific/legible/understandable, I think that would help. Maybe you could ask a friend to review it and then either make some edits/updates to it, or re-post a corrected new question later.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. Your page is HTML5 since you declared it in your [doctype](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/doctype.htm).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

If you want to know more about HTML5 specific tags or functions, browse [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5?sort=frequent) or [google for tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=get+started+with+html5).